# How does git branching work with Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, branch

[image: ----------]

I created two local git branches for this project (master and old). I recently push/pulled to/from Heroku as well and I was surprised to discover two branches associated with Heroku (branch and master) as well. I'm still new to git ... can anyone please help me understand what's going on with regard to my branches based on the image above?

I'm happy with my local branch called "master" and I'm fine with eliminating all other branches at this point. Any tips on how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of `git branch -avv` and `git config push.default`?

Answer (score 1):

```
* branch     master    -> FETCH_HEAD
```

This line indicates that you synced up your local repo's `master` branch with the change from the remote repo's `master` branch.

The git branch command as you mentioned indicates two branches `master` and `old`. And you've currently checked out the `master` branch which is indicated with an `*` in the beginning of the branch name.

To delete the branch named `old` use the following command:

```
git branch -D old
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git fetch` to update your remote branches.

Afterwards use `git branch -avv` to see which local and remote branches exist.

Check `git config push.default` to see how you git is configured to do on `git push`.
(Depending on you git version there are different defaults. It probably defaults to pushing *all* local branches. See push.default in `man git config` for details.)

You can delete a local branch with `git branch -d old`. You can delete a remote branch with `git push --delete old; git fetch -p`.